How can I best use tar and gpg to create and restore multi-tape backups?
I'm trying to create a backup spanning multiple tapes (on a manual loading drive) using tar and some form of encryption.  Here's what I've been using (partially based on, iirc, an answer from Encrypt backups with GPG to multiple tapes):
mt -f $TAPE rewind; tar --ignore-failed-read -cf - <dirtree> \
  | gpg -c --compress-algo none --pinentry-mode loopback \
  | mbuffer -m 24G -P 95% -f -o $TAPE \
    -A "echo next tape; mt -f $TAPE eject ; read a < /dev/tty"

This works great with «mt -f $TAPE rewind ; dd if=$TAPE bs=8M | gpg -d --passphrase | tar -x» for restore from single-tape backups and from the first tape in a multi-tape backup.  But I can't quite figure out the recipe for reversing the backup sequence across multiple tapes.  Here are a couple variants I've been trying to get a file list on the second tape...
mt -f $TAPE rewind; mbuffer -i $TAPE -m 24G -P 95% -A "echo next tape; mt -f $TAPE eject ; read a < /dev/tty; mt -f $TAPE rewind" | gpg -d | tar -t


mt -f $TAPE rewind; dd if=$TAPE bs=8M | gpg -d --passphrase | tar --multi-volume -t

And here's my most recent error (after a bunch of files successfully listed on the first tape)...
gpg: block_filter 0x0000558e3b208230: read error (size=36854,a->size=1535012014164377600 bytes (12 TB, 11 TiB) copied,
41413.2 s, 290 MB/s
)
gpg: block_filter 0x0000558e3b208d70: read error (size=33201,a->size=17841)
gpg: WARNING: encrypted message has been manipulated!
gpg: block_filter: pending bytes!
gpg: block_filter: pending bytes!
Prepare volume #2 for ‘-’ and hit return:
tar: -: Cannot open: Bad file descriptor
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

And when I try to directly read from tape #2 without going through tape #1 first, I get an error like "gpg: packet(13) too large"
Any suggestions on reading the tape set created with my original backup script would be great, but I'm also willing to just start from scratch and back up with a different command sequence.

I would not use encryption on tapes. If it's valuable data, store the tapes in a safe. PS when working with tapes, keep it simple, or face data losses

The data contains HIPAA-protected personal health information, so I'm hesitant to throw plain text and data on devices that I'll be handing off to administrators/managers who might not be as paranoid as I am.  Still, if it ends up being my only feasible option, I'll put serious consideration into your suggestion.

The linked answer has some warnings about the fact that if you write to the tape using mbuffer you will need to read from the tape using mbuffer as well. Have you tried that?

Yes, the first example I gave above of an attempted restore follows the rewind starting with "mbuffer -i $TAPE".
